# Percorrer uma matriz e validar números repetidos

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Estou realizando um trabalho final no primeiro semestre no curso de BCC e preciso fazer um algoritmo de Mega Sena com as seguintes características:

- Máximo de 10 jogadores
- Cada jogador deve apostar um mínimo de 6 números e máximo de 15 números
- Os números válidos vão de 1 a 60
- As apostas não podem se repetir

A linguagem utilizada é o Portugol, mas usamos uma plataforma específica criada por alunos da Universidade, então há pequenas variações na semântica do código em relação ao comum Visualg.

Minha dúvida é em relação a apenas uma parte específica do código que não consegui solucionar a parte de apostas não se repetirem. Se o usuário aposta o número 1, o número 1 não poderá mais ser utilizado por ninguém. Segue imagem do código.

Eu suponho que a resolução para esse problema possa ser resolvida percorrendo a matriz por completo e verificando cada aposta, mas não consegui encontrar um método funcional para isso.

Quem puder ajudar, sinta-se à vontade em utilizar a própria linguagem C.

[image]

Comment: O requisito é mesmo "se o usuário aposta o número 1, o número 1 não poderá mais ser utilizado por ninguém"? Que estranho isso!

Comment: Bom, foi o que eu entendi, mas posso ter interpretado errado. O enunciado diz "Deve-se salientar que os números apostados não podem ser repetidos e devem ser escolhidos entre os valores de 1 a 60". Imagino que fiz uma pequena confusão... Jogador 1 aposta: 1,2,3,4,5,6.. ele não poderá apostar o 1 novamente, mas os outros jogadores podem apostar o 1, talvez...

Comment: Ou talvez a restrição seja que não pode haver números repetidos *na mesma aposta* (ex: 1 1 2 2 3 3), como na mega sena de verdade.

Comment: Imagino que seja isto mesmo, mas ainda não consegui implementar tal validação corretamente no código.. Suponho que deva percorrer todo o vetor e verificar se o número está lá, mas sempre que tento, recebo um erro dizendo que o vetor não foi inicializado.

Comment: O método seria esse mesmo, mas não posso te ajudar com esse código, pois sei pouco de C e menos ainda de Portugol. O erro que você citou é do portugol ou do compilador c?

Comment: É do próprio Portugol.

Comment: Tente postar código em vez de imagem de código. Não sei se Portugol tem [**Syntax Highlight**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150/201), mas talvez outra linguagem sirva.

Comment: O próprio Calango já possui Syntax Highlight. As palavras em azul são as palavras reservadas.

Answer (score 1):

Antes do vetor[contador1][contador2] receber a aposta, faca um loop (para...faca) para verificar se a aposta informada já está dentro do vetor. Se tiver, pede para o usuário informar o numero novamente.

Algo do tipo:

```
leia(apostas);

para (contador3 de 1 ate 15) faca
       se (vetor[contador1][contador3] = apostas)
          ir para (goto) leia(apostas);      
fimpara
```

Comment: Com tal implementação, recebo um erro "A variável 'vetor[1][1]' não foi inicializada".

Comment: Tente zerar o vetor antes de tudo.
`loop ate 2`
`loop ate 15`
`vetor[][] = 0;`

Comment: Tente substituir no código acima o seguinte: para (contador3 de 1 ate (contador2 - 1)) faca ... Isso garante que você nunca vai testar os slots do array que ainda não receberam valores de apostas (não inicializados)

Comment: Infelizmente continuo recebendo erros de "vetor não inicializado". Imagino que há algum modo de após ler os 6 números, verificar dentro do vetor se há números repetidos, mas também estou obtendo erro de não inicialização do vetor.